# Pentaho Data Integration - Merge rows (diff) step not executing with Table Input "Replace variables in script"

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have a PDI Transformation that is using the `Merge rows (diff)` step comparing rows from two `Table Input` steps (with `Sort`s in between). (I linked a screenshot of the Transformation at the bottom of the post)

The queries in the `Table Input` require parameters to be passed, so the options `Replace variables in script?`, `Insert data from step`, and `Execute for each row?` are all active / filled.
With these options disabled / empty and a value hardcoded where the parameter is now defined, the `Merge rows (diff)` is working properly and marking the rows with the correct state (`new`, `changed`, ...).
On the other hand, if I try to run this Transformation with the options active, passing a parameter, the `Merge rows (diff)` seems to not be executed - there is a `Write to log` step after it and it is not printing anything, opposed to when the options are disabled and the "parameter" is hardcoded.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? Is the `Merge rows (diff)` step not implemented to work in this scenario?

Thank you in advance to everyone that might have an idea or suggestion.
Cheers

[Screenshot of the simplified PDI Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q6zm.png).

**Update #1:** Add screenshot of `Step Metrics` as requested in the comments.
For the entity that was tested, `Compare Rows` returns 4 rows, while `Reference Rows` does not - this had the desired result of having 4 rows marked as `new` by the `Merge rows (diff)` step. I will also duplicate this entity to the `Reference Rows` table and upload a new screenshot with `Step Metrics` where both `Table Input` queries return the same rows.

[image]

**Update #2:** Add seconds screenshot of `Step Metrics` - where both `Table Input` steps output rows (and the same rows). `Merge rows (diff)` still does not output anything. Uploading this screenshot I noticed an issue - the `Sort` steps were not returning rows, so I replaced them with an `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL queries in the `Table Input` steps, added the `Write to log` steps, and now the `Merge rows (diff)` step is getting and outputting rows - even though it should be outputting 4 as `identical` instead of the 3 it does, but that is outside the scope of this post.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of you step metric? (On the execution results tab). Most likely table inputs are not returning any rows, which is why merge rows doesn’t do anything.

Comment: Also: check order of incoming fields. Parameters are passed in the other they arrive. You may want to put 2 write to log steps BEFORE each table input.

Comment: Hello @nsousa, I've been trying to upload a screenshot since 7 hours ago, but apparently some people are having [trouble uploading images today]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420821/server-error-failed-to-upload-image-an-error-occurred-on-the-server)

Comment: Without step metrics I can’t confirm my theory. But if there are 0 rows written by the table input steps the problem is in your table input steps and/or their parameters, not the merge rows.

Comment: @nsousa the image upload on stackoverflow problem seems to be solved. I added the screenshot you requested. Only one of the `Table Input` steps writes something, since the other returns no rows (since they are `new` rows)

Comment: @nsousa by analysing the `Step Metrics` metrics you suggested, I realised the `Sort` steps were not returning rows - so I replaced them by ordering the rows directly in SQL - and now `Merge rows (diff)` is actually outputting rows, and correctly marking them with `identical` (even though it only returns 3 instead of 4). Thank you for the suggestion and the resolution. I will investigate further why a row is missing from the output and then answer my own post with the fix

Comment: Sort rows isn't returning rows because it's still running. Sort will only produce output AFTER the incoming stream finishes (which is when sorting can start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "fix" was to remove the `Sort row` steps and replace the ordering by an `ORDER BY` in the SQL query of the `Table Input` steps.